# jquery ul list filter only works when the search-keywords are in a row/consecutively

Tags: jquery, search, filter

I have little problem with a jquery filter function that get from the internet and modified it for my purpose.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TKL9Y/)

And here are the code:

```
    (function ($) {
// custom css expression for a case-insensitive contains()
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};


function listFilter(header, list) { // header is any element, list is an unordered list
// create and add the filter form to the header
var form = $("<form>").attr({"class":"filterform","action":"#"}),
input = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterinput","type":"text", "value":"Live-Filterfunktion"});
$(form).append(input).appendTo(header);
$(input)
.change( function () {

var filter = $(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();

$('.serien a').each(function(i, el){
    text = $(el).text().replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
    index = text.indexOf(filter);
    if(index != -1){
        // The substring is contained -> show parent
        //console.log($(this).attr('id')+' contains '+filter);
        //$(this).find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().fadeIn();
        $(this).parent().show();

    }else{
        // The substring is not contained -> hide parent
        //console.log($(this).attr('id')+' does not contain '+filter);
        //$(this).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().fadeOut();
        $(this).parent().hide();
    }
});


return false;
})
.keyup( function () {
// fire the above change event after every letter
$(this).change();
});
}
//ondomready
$(function () {
listFilter($(".filter"), $(".list"));
});



$(function() {
    $(".filterinput").focus(function() {
      $(this).val('')
      $(this).change();

      });
 });

}(jQuery));
```

The filter works great, I even get it to ignore the whitespaces. But I have one problem that i cant get fixed. The match for the filter only works when the search keyword(s) are in a row.

Example for the [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/TKL9Y/)

Type in the input-field "John Wayne" or even "johnwayne" and it works fine!
But now type "John Tayler" and it didnt work cause the search keywords are not in a row/consecutively but the list contains both keywords. I tried and tried but i cant get it work.

So I hope I can get here some help, it would be great.
Sorry for my bad englisch Im from Poland.

Greetings!

Comment: You most likely need to split the filter text by space and then search for each element of that array individually.

Comment: Can you give me a little or big :P starthelp pls, cause I really dont know how to make this. I am glad that I get so far as I am ;)